# meta tag content not changing with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, meta-tags, meta

I have a problem. 
I have used jQuery for meta content change, but meta content not changed. How to change meta content with jQuery. 
Thanks!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <meta id="meta-element" property='og:title' content="the title"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="the desciption" />

    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
            $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content", 'My title');
        </script>

        <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
        <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
        <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-599ab21e622f447a"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Should work. What template engine are you using? Does it change `og:title` to something else?

Comment: The code posted works just fine ([proof](http://output.jsbin.com/qohujeloko/); use right-click and "Inspect element" to see the updated value).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  You are right. "Inspect element"  showing changed meta title but when I click social share its showing old meta title "the  title"

Comment: because it prefetch the value of meta title. That is it store the value of meta title before you change it

Comment: @Redo: I was thinking that too, but I can't see how with the quoted code/markup. The `script` element making the change is clearly before the `script` element including what I assume is the thing using it at the bottom (since I don't think Bootstrap does). It shouldn't be *able* to get it before the inline script changes it. Of course, perhaps the above has been edited.

Answer (score -2):

You can use your jQuery in following manner:

```
<script>
    $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", 'My title');
 </script>
```

If you are using chrome (don't use property, use name):

```
<script>
 $("meta[name='og:title']").attr("content", 'My title');
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried the same before I answered here and its working (don't know why downvoted)